# Access to a join entity in twig

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm a beginner in symfony/twig and i need help to understand how to access variable from a join entity in twig

- I've 2 entities : `Avdert` with a one-to-one relationship with the entity `Image`
- I created an `index.html`.twig where all my `Advert` are listed using the variable `$listAdverts` it's OK I've the list of all my adverts

I want to display a small image near each of my Advert, if I look using `dump` what's in `advert.image` I've `id` and `url` of image it's OK.
So I thought that as I just needed to use `advert.image.url` to access the url of the image, but instead I'm getting this error:

> "Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a null variable"

I'm missing something but what ?

Comment: Are you sure each advert has an image?

Comment: haaa some adverts didn't have image i've add images and that's working !! thanks :) what does the error message means in fact ?

Comment: It means that some advert in your loop didn't have an image attached to it... You can prevent this by adding a condition around you code: `{% if advert.image is defined %}{{ advert.image.url }}{% endif %}`. This would prevent the error

Comment: Ok i understand thanks :)

Comment: How can i accept your answer DarkBee ?

Comment: You can't as I didn't provide an answer, just a comment :)